# String manipulation for TV Show titles using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, filenames

I have a string containing a filename that typically contains Season, Episode, Quality and Release information.  I am trying to remove the unwanted area of text that follows the season and episode.  So far I have managed to put this together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

filenames = [
    "remy.and.papoose.meet.the.mackies.s01e01.1080p.web.x264-tbs", 
    "remy.and.papoose.meet.the.mackies.s01e01.1080p.web.x264-tbs", 
    "Bodyguard.S01E10.720p.iP.WEB-DL.AAC2.0.H.264-BTN", 
    "Empire.2015.S05E01.Steal.From.the.Thief.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DD.5.1.H.264-AJP69", 
    "Better.Call.Saul.S04E09.720p.HDTV.x264-AVS"
]

for filename in filenames:

    filename = filename.replace(".", " ").lower()
    stringRemove = re.sub('.*[s|S][0-9]{2}[e|E][0-9]{2}', '', filename)
    cleanFilename = filename.replace(stringRemove, "")

    print(cleanFilename)
```

This code WORKS.

**EDIT**: I'd like to know if I can improve the regex to catch any variants of the filename string that I may not have thought of? Has anyone had to do string replacements on filenames that contain season, episodes, quality and release in the name?

Comment: Just glimpsing at your post, it's bloated and lacking at the same time, you have provided your expected output and input, but all the extra text is overkill, instead of explaining what you are thinking or going to or actually attempted, it would be better to just show your attempt, what its producing, if you provide the information needed, the help will appear

Comment: The simple solution to that is: `string.replace(".", " ")`, then use `re.match` with a regex like:   `(.*[s|S][0-9]{2}[e|E][0-9]{2})`. Hope it helps, and next time, please try to write a short and concise  question :)

Comment: If your code is working as intended and is bug free, perhaps you would want to try posting here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Frankly your question is still pretty broad asking if there's anyway to improve it. Could you narrow it down to a specific thing or two on what you want to improve on? As it stands the question is still pretty broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question and have updated it to reflect this with example code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

filenames = [
    "remy.and.papoose.meet.the.mackies.s01e01.1080p.web.x264-tbs", 
    "remy.and.papoose.meet.the.mackies.s01e01.1080p.web.x264-tbs", 
    "Bodyguard.S01E10.720p.iP.WEB-DL.AAC2.0.H.264-BTN", 
    "Empire.2015.S05E01.Steal.From.the.Thief.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DD.5.1.H.264-AJP69", 
    "Better.Call.Saul.S04E09.720p.HDTV.x264-AVS"
]

for filename in filenames:

    filename = filename.replace(".", " ").lower()
    stringRemove = re.sub('.*[s|S][0-9]{2}[e|E][0-9]{2}', '', filename)
    cleanFilename = filename.replace(stringRemove, "")

    print(cleanFilename)
```